# MDX how to get total sum for sub groups?

Tags: ssas, mdx

I have MDX query like following:

```
SELECT
NON EMPTY { [Measures].[Sales Amount] } ON COLUMNS,
NON EMPTY { ([Customer].[City].[City] * [Customer].[Gender].[Gender] ) } ON ROWS
FROM [Analysis Services Tutorial]
```

This MDX Query gets following table result as you know:

```
|---------------------|-----------|---------------|
|        City         |   Gender  |  Sales Amount |
|---------------------|-----------|---------------|
|     Ballard         |     F     |    300        |
|---------------------|-----------|---------------|
|     Ballard         |     M     |    500        |
|---------------------|-----------|---------------|
|     Berkeley        |     F     |    200        |
|---------------------|-----------|---------------|
|     Berkeley        |     M     |    100        |
|---------------------|-----------|---------------|
                      .
                      .
                      .
```

But I need sub totals in the table like that:

```
|---------------------|-----------|---------------|
|        City         |   Gender  |  Sales Amount |
|---------------------|-----------|---------------|
|     Ballard         |     F     |    300        |
|---------------------|-----------|---------------|
|     Ballard         |     M     |    500        |
|---------------------|-----------|---------------|
|     Ballard         |    All    |    800        |
|---------------------|-----------|---------------|
|     Berkeley        |     F     |    200        |
|---------------------|-----------|---------------|
|     Berkeley        |     M     |    100        |
|---------------------|-----------|---------------|
|     Berkeley        |    All    |    300        |
|---------------------|-----------|---------------|
                      .
                      .
                      .
```

Is there any suggestion to do that in MDX? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may add the ALL member:

```
SELECT
NON EMPTY [Measures].[Sales Amount] ON COLUMNS,
NON EMPTY [Customer].[City].[City].Members * {[Customer].[Gender].[Gender].Members + [Customer].[Gender].[All]} ON ROWS
FROM [Analysis Services Tutorial]
```

Or all members of the Gender hierarchy:

```
SELECT
NON EMPTY { [Measures].[Sales Amount] } ON COLUMNS,
NON EMPTY [Customer].[City].[City].Members * [Customer].[Gender].Members ON ROWS
FROM [Analysis Services Tutorial]
```

Comment: the first option should be a very alternative option ... your second script is the answer

Comment: Not really, if the Gender hierarchy is multi-level it may be misused.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this query

```
SELECT
NON EMPTY { [Measures].[Sales Amount] } ON COLUMNS,
NON EMPTY { ([Customer].[City].[City] * [Customer].[Gender].allmembers ) } ON ROWS
FROM [Analysis Services Tutorial]
```

you generally need to use allmembers to be able to display the All member. If that didn't return the All member, then you need to calculate it as such

```
WITH Member [Customer].[Gender].[All Genders] AS [Customer].[Gender].&[M] + 
                                                 [Customer].[Gender].&[F] 
SELECT
NON EMPTY { [Measures].[Sales Amount] } ON COLUMNS,
NON EMPTY { ([Customer].[City].[City] * [Customer].[Gender].allmembers ) } ON ROWS
FROM [Analysis Services Tutorial]
```